# DRY Custom Guice Provider with parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I need multiple instances of `X` being injected in different places. 
I implemented a custom Guice Provider to provide different instances of a class X as following.

```
public class XProvider implements Provider<X> {
    private final Factory f;
    private final String NAME = "Something String";

    @Inject
    public XProvider(Factory f) {
       this.f = f;
    }

    public X get() {
        return new X(f, NAME);
    }
}
```

Because I need different instance of X with different value of `NAME`, I need to have multiple similar classes 
like XProvider1, XProvider2, etc. that only different in one field. 
Create an abstract class to extend from doesn't help reduce the amount of redundant code because (1) hiding field is not good 
(2) if I don't hide field, I still need to have the constructor in the subclass anyway.

I can't used Assisted Injection because I don't own `X` so I change its constructor.

There must be a better way to do it, either a smarter way to use Guice or another to restructure my code. 
I'm looking for some advice for change here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have predefined limited set of possible arguments, you can use named @Provides binding in guice module:

```
@Provides @Named("Type 1") MyClass getType1() {return new MyClass("Param of type 1");}
@Provides @Named("Type 2") MyClass getType2() {return new MyClass("Param of type 2");}
```

and then inject it with names

```
@Inject @Named("Type 1") 
private MyClass instance, anotherInstance;
```

ps. You can pass any injectable parameters to @Provides methods, ie getType2(Factory factory) {return ...